# How can I create ParallelPeriod for Time Range (Time Set)

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I need to build KPI Goal Expression for parallel period

Example:

`(ParallelPeriod([Time].[Calendar].[Year],1, [Time].[Calendar].CurrentMember), [Measures].[MyCubeMember])`

This expression works for Year, Quarter, Month, Week but doesn't work where in query is time range

Example:

```
{[Time].[Calendar].[Quarter].&[201401] : [Time].[Calendar].[Quarter].&[201402]}
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained by one of the developers of MDX in SSAS [in this article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2007/01/13/multiselect-friendly-mdx-for-calculations-looking-at-current-coordinate.aspx), multi-selection is tricky. You can use the less efficient but working code more or less directly from this article and change your code to:

```
Aggregate(EXISTING [Time].[Calendar].Members,
          (ParallelPeriod([Time].[Calendar].[Year],1), [Measures].[MyCubeMember])
         )
```